# migrating from perl to php

Tags: php, windows, perl, laravel

I have no experience in Perl at all, and also beginner in PHP. I need to migrate the old company system using Perl to new one using PHP. Here is some code in Perl I didn't understand:

```
while (my $data=$query->fetchrow_hashref) {
        push @oid_list, $data->{oid};
        push @{$snmp_order->{$sensor}}, $data->{function};
        $oid_hash->{$sensor}->{$data->{function}}->{oid}=$data->{oid};
        $oid_hash->{$sensor}->{$data->{function}}->{scale}=$data->{scale};
    }
```

Can someone explain what does the code mean and what it will become in PHP? Also, what does `$a->{$b}` mean in Perl?

I've been trying to figure it out since 3 days but still having difficulties dealing with it.

Comment: Ask the guy who developed it, maybe?

Comment: @CaelanGrgurovic I don't know where you've worked in the past, but it's happened to me far too often that the original programmer is no longer around to help!

Comment: [perlreftut](http://p3rl.org/perlreftut), [perlref](http://p3rl.org/perlref), 
[perllol](http://p3rl.org/perllol), [perldsc](http://p3rl.org/perldsc).

Comment: Oh :/ I'm only 15 so I've never had a chance to work at a programming company :( most of them require you to be 18 or older where I am.

Comment: Perhaps this will help? http://perldoc.perl.org/index-language.html and http://php.net/manual/en No serious, you seem very ill-equiped to do this task. Syntax shouldn't be a stumbling block.

Comment: That's horrendous Perl. The guy who wrote it didn't want people to understand it, I reckon. I think it's reading from a database to create a hash of hashes, but I can't see what that data is then used for, because that code is not included. I would be tempted to use Perl's Data::Dumper library to view the resulting data structure, and then re-write it in PHP from scratch.

Comment: I don't know how you spent your three days trying to figure it out, but if I had to use a language that I knew nothing about, I'd get [a good book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781118013847.do) and spend the first couple of days working through that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't use php, but I try to explain the code in general:

```
# while there is data in the object that is returned by calling the method "fetchrow_hashref" of the object $query: it means, get a single data row from the database 
while (my $data=$query->fetchrow_hashref) {

    # add the value stored in field "oid" from the hash "data" to array "oid_list"
    # what is hash? kind of array indexed by strings. Red more about hashes here: http://perlmaven.com/perl-hashes
    push @oid_list, $data->{oid};

    # add the value stored in field "function" of the hash "data" to 
    # an array that is found in a reference, which reference is stored in hash "snmp_order" under 
    # a field that is named the same as the value of variable $sensor
    push @{$snmp_order->{$sensor}}, $data->{function};

    # now: the data->oid is added to oid_hash. I will use array notation to explain where it lands:
    # oid_hash[$sensor][$data->{function}][oid] =  $data->{oid}
    $oid_hash->{$sensor}->{$data->{function}}->{oid}=$data->{oid};

    # oid_hash[$sensor][$data->{function}][scale] =  $data->{scale}
    # $sensor and $data->{function} are variables!
    $oid_hash->{$sensor}->{$data->{function}}->{scale}=$data->{scale};
}
```

You can read more about Perl hashes, for example here (I repeat myself): http://perlmaven.com/perl-hashes

Comment: Ah, you were faster :)

Comment: Thank you so much ! @Piotr really helping me

Answer (score 3):

Well since I'm not an php-programmer I just can tell you what the perl-code means. Maybe it helps you a bit further!

```
#an query to the Database was fired through the DBI-module from Perl
#the result is temporarily stored in the $query but has to be fetched
#before further use. Since the result could contain multiple rows the $data
#is filled with each row while the ->fetchrow_hashref() function returns a hash of
#data representing one returned row of the query. The keys of the hash are the column
#names of the database-table
while(my $data = $query->fetchrow_hashref){...}
```

The `@` indicates an array in Perl. So the `@oid_list` is treated as one. Therefore it is possible to push a value `$data->{oid}` into it (`push @oid_list, $data->{oid}`).

The Syntax `$data->{oid}` is a bit more complex. Imagine that the `$data` is a **reference** (simply a pointer) to a Hash (or in other languages like java called Map). But you rather want to access the **hash behind** this reference. So you use the `->` to **dereference** the pointer and access the real hash the `$data` is pointing to. By `$data->{oid}` you acces the value behind the key `oid` in the Hashreferenceby `$data`.

A similiar thing happens in the `push @{$snmp_order->{$sensor}}, $data->{function};`. But here you first have to access the real array behind the reference `$snmp_order->{$sensor}`. Here a key of an referenced hash contains a **array reference** that is getting pushe the value `$data->{function};` into it.

The rest of the code is a kind of these two things. The programmer just assigns different values from the fetched database-row `$data` into different keys of a big hash-reference `$oid_hash`. Within the `{}` you will always find the name of the key which is accessed.